# Wavelink TelnetCE pass login parameters in config file

Tags: telnet

I'm using Wavelink TelnetCE (Compact Edition on a hand-held). This works very similar to a ftp client (like putty). I'm writing an application to first login to this device and then we have a menu which has an menu-item to invoke Wavelink. Now, the idea is we need to automatically login to the telnetCE client without supplying the user credentials. When we initially login to the applications, the credentials are written to a config file (or persisted while the session is active) and when we click on the telnet menu item, the credentials are automatically read from the the persisted source and login happens automatically.

All code is written in C# .NET CE. Any assistance/ ideas would be helpful. To start off, i need to know if this is actually possible? and if there is such a config file - how to access the same prior to invoking the application.